# How do I get form results from another website with GET or cURL

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I'm trying to use either cURL or a GET request to retrieve results from form submission to a company website

I am trying to get flight status results from aa.com using a php script.

The form lives at https://www.aa.com/homePage.do >> Flight Status (search by Flight Number and Date) and when you enter data on the form you get flight status and the URL that is in the address window looks like:

https://www.aa.com/travelInformation/flights/status/detail?search=AA|1698|2019,1,23&ref=search

Where 1698 is the flight number and 2019,1,23 is the url formatted date after selecting Wednesday, January 23 on the date dropdown.

I have tried using both file_get_contents to the page such as:

```
    $flight_data = file_get_contents("https://www.aa.com/travelInformation/flights/status/detail?search=AA|$flight|$formatted_date|&ref=search");
```

where $flight and $formatted date are replaced with form input from my site.

```
    $flight_data = file_get_contents("https://www.aa.com/travelInformation/flights/status/detail?search=AA|1698|2019,01,23|&ref=search");
```

When this is processed and I print the result to the screen, it does NOT contain the flight status information, it only contains some generic output.

When I use cURL to attempt to get the data:

```
    $target = 'https://www.aa.com/travelInformation/flights/status/lookup';

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5";

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//perform our request
$flight_data = curl_exec($ch);

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo curl_errno($ch) . '-' .
    curl_error($ch);

//close the connection
curl_close($ch);*/

print $flight_data;
```

I get the same generic output.

What I expect to get is the source of the page as if I had actually gone to aa.com and entered the flight information on their form.  I then want to parse that result to get all the flights with a given flight number on a given date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is generic output? When you try to get above URL, you should receive only html, use one html parser in order to parse it.

Comment: They seem to have measures in place against this, which likely also means they do not really want you to do this in the first place.

Comment: Duy... It is html, but it does not contain the flight information I get when I submit the form on the aa.com site

Comment: For clarification, when I go to:  https://www.aa.com/travelInformation/flights/status/detail?search=AA|1698|2019,1,21&ref=search ,     the flight information occasionally shows up in Safari but never in Chrome.  To make it even weirder, if the flight information is not visible, it becomes visible if I select any element for inspection, and in all cases the source for the flight information is not included when I look at the page source.

Comment: I _think_ I have found a solution by using phantomJS